# How can I import my logging set up instead of hardcoding it into a script?

Tags: python, logging

Is it possible for me to have my logging setup be imported into scripts instead of having to hardcode it into each individual one? I mainly want to reduce redundancy with this.

The code I add to each script right now is this:

```py
import logging
import sys

# enable logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt="%(asctime)s - <%(filename)s:%(funcName)s> %(levelname)s: %(message)s",
                              datefmt="%Y-%m-%d - %H:%M:%S")
ch = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
fh = logging.FileHandler("updates.log", "a")
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
log.addHandler(ch)
log.addHandler(fh)
```

This allows me to just say `log.info('this thing happened!')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encapsulate your logging configurations in a function and call it in the beginning of different files.

In file `logging_utils.py`:

```
import logging
import sys

def log_setup():
    log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt="%(asctime)s - <%(filename)s:%(funcName)s> %(levelname)s: %(message)s", datefmt="%Y-%m-%d - %H:%M:%S")
    ch = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    ch.setFormatter(formatter)
    fh = logging.FileHandler("updates.log", "a")
    fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    log.addHandler(ch)
    log.addHandler(fh)
    return log
```

In `main.py`:

```
from logging_utils import setup_log

log = setup_log()

log.info('this log will work as planned!')
```

Comment: For actually logging info would I have to call setup_log() every time? Or how can I still log using something like `log.info('this thing happened!')`

Comment: Ah, nevermind. I just need to do `log = setup_log()` since it is returning log and it works. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! Consider using this method to encapsulate other setup instruction you may have, such as matplotlib configurations, constants you want to use, etc.